# Convert 15.10 Vanilla to GNOME Edition

Tags: gnome, 15.10

How can i convert my Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit Vanilla Unity installation to Ubuntu GNOME Edition. Is it just installing Gnome Shell and uninstalling Unity. However i dont think this will be enough. Am I right, and if so, how can i convert to Ubuntu Gnome Edition?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(ubuntu),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(gnome))))'
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(unity),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(gnome))))'
apt-get install --reinstall gnome
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

This removes the installed packages that reverse-depend on Ubuntu and Unity and not those for gnome.

Comment: But that is not installing Gnome, right?